# Frequency Response Sketch from zeros (FIR filter)

Tags: filter

The question is

*Sketch the frequency response of an FIR filter with zeros at $$z=e^{j2\pi/3} and z=e^{j4\pi/3}$$*

Here's my approach

[image]

Now when I use these formulas and plug in say omega=0, I'm getting 2 as my answer however the correct answer is 3. I think my formulae for L1 and L2 and incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Should be \$L_1=\sqrt{(cos(\omega) -cos(2\pi/3))^2+(sin(\omega)-sin(2\pi/3))^2}\$, etc....

Comment: I thought the modulus of complex number is the square root of the real part squared + imaginary part squared

Comment: It is, but if you have two complex numbers added or subtracted you must first combine them: \$(x+jy)-(u+jv)=(x-u)+j(y-v)\$, then find the modulus.